# Strapi 4 Assign record to a An admin user

Tags: strapi

I’m using strapi v4.20.0 . And i have a couple of collections in there .
I have 2 roles 1 admin and moderator .

i don’t know if this is possible . but I want to assign a record in products collection to a moderator so he can have access to it .

i have set up a relation between products and users . product has many users .

in the RBAC I set that he can see and update if he is the creator … but I want to make him see the record and update it if he’s in relation with a product …

any idea how can this be done ? or is it even possible in strapi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to achieve that.
You will have to create a custom condition for that.
Here is the documentation: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/rbac

In my case, I created a many-way relation between Products and Admin Users.
The key is "Shared_with" - so updated it accordingly to your needs.

Then, you will have to create the custom condition.

```
    await strapi.admin.services.permission.conditionProvider.register({
      displayName: 'Shared with',
      name: 'shared-with',
      plugin: 'admin',
      handler: async (user) => {
        return  {
          "Shared_with": {
            $elemMatch: {
              id: user.id
            }
          }
        }
      },
    });
  },
```

Once it's created, you will have to apply it to your Collection Type.

And voilà.

Here is a video to help you going though that:
https://www.loom.com/share/2490ed5def6e46fb8adacabbc80f1d2d?sid=ec166e58-7536-4ee2-85fc-afee79614834

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Jim. is there any way I can change the entry title to use email instead of id? i tried changing it but had no luck still shows the id of the users .. its kinda of useless to use IDs I cant even see the IDs of admin users in the panel

Comment: I can see the id in the API response in SETTINGS / ADMINSITRATION PANEL / Users . but it's not displayed on table . is there a way to display it ?

Comment: Hello 
While testing it for the video, I spotted that issue too.
Related to that one: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/18072
I shared that with the team, will see when we are able to prio it